# Запрос на несколько значений

Tags: php, mysql

К примеру есть структура таблицы товара и в ней есть столбец `categ_id`  и у него через запятую указаны категории `categ_id`=1,2,3
 Как сформировать запрос,чтобы к примеру проверить только на принадлежность ко 2 категории?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

слегка подправлено из офф. документации MySql:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('2','1,2,3,4');
```

т.е. условие `WHERE`  дополнится `AND FIND_IN_SET(...)`